# File path issue while including a file from other files at various directories

Tags: php, html, css, path, relative-path

File Structure:

```
app/
 - index.php
 - core -> header.php, setup.php
 - img -> ...
 - lib -> css->stylesheet.css, js->script.js
```

I have a `header.php` file that contains link to CSS and JS files.
It looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/stylesheet.css"/>
<script src="lib/js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I need to include `header.php` in two other files: index.php and setup.php.

The file loads fine in `index.php` since `app/lib/css/stylesheet.css` and `app/lib/js/script.js` exist.
In case of loading from `setup.php`, it will look for file inside the directory `'app/core/lib/css ... and js ... '`.

I tried solving this problem using absolute path using something like:

```
$path = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

and appending it to link and script tags in `header.php`
The problem is that windows says cant access local resources.

How do I solve this sort of issue? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make a config.php file with configurations like

```
<?php
$webPath = 'http://example.com/';
$jsPath = $webpath . 'lib/js/';
$cssPath = $webPath . 'lib/css/';
```

Then include config.php in all of your entry points. Entry point here is index.php and setup.php

Once you have that, header.php should have simple code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= $cssPath ?>stylesheet.css"/>
<script src="<?= $jsPath ?>script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should include your files whether .js or .css files using http:// protocol.
You can define constant in your config file as shown below:

```
define('SITE','http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/<project_name>/');
```

Now you can use SITE constant in your header.php as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo SITE;?>lib/css/stylesheet.css"/>
<script src="<?php echo SITE;?>lib/js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hope it help you. :)

Comment: Thanks, I shouldn't have used realpath.